MySQL query optimizer makes poor choice of index on big tables
I have multiple databases with identical structure but different data. I am running my query against them, and for some databases the query works quickly and for some it is slow.
This is the query:
SELECT *
FROM table_a
JOIN table_b ON table_b.id = table_a.table_b_id
ORDER BY table_a.id
LIMIT 100

Table A is inner-joined to Table B, and I only need the rows where the corresponding entry in the Table B exists. The column table_b_id does not have a foreign key constraint.
Most of the time the query works well, and this is what EXPLAIN shows me:



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
table_a

index
ix_table_a_table_b_id
PRIMARY
1002

100
100.0



1
SIMPLE
table_b

eq_ref
PRIMARY
PRIMARY
1002
table_a.table_b_id
1
100.0
Using where



This makes sense: using primary key of Table A, get first 100 rows from Table A, then get the ids that reference Table B, then get rows with these ids from Table B using its primary key.
However, for some databases the query is slow and this is the EXPLAIN output:



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
table_b

ALL
PRIMARY



7842
90.0
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort


1
SIMPLE
table_a

ref
ix_table_a_table_b_id
ix_table_a_table_b_id
1003
table_b.id
87
100.0




If I explicitly tell MySQL to use the PRIMARY indices, the query works quickly on all databases (and EXPLAIN output is the same on all databases too):
SELECT *
FROM table_a USE INDEX (PRIMARY)
JOIN table_b USE INDEX (PRIMARY)
ON table_b.id = table_a.table_b_id
ORDER BY table_a.id
LIMIT 100

What am I doing wrong to make the optimizer fail in such a way? Is there really no better solution than to explicitly tell it to use specific indices?

and I only need the rows where the corresponding entry in the Table B exists ... then why use a LEFT JOIN? Simply JOIN table_b ON table_b.id = table_a.table_b_id and remove the WHERE clause.

The column table_b_id does not have a foreign key constraint - so add it

@MatteoTassinari Surprisingly enough, using inner join makes no difference, but I will rewrite the question to use inner join.

The plans shows that the server selects unsafe tables scanning order. Try to fix the scanning order with STRAIGHT_JOIN. Also this can be an effect of unprecise data statistic - so try to renew it. If the tables are "big" (how many rows is your "big"?) then use not table_a but limited subquery from this table.

@Akina Thank you! Running FLUSH TABLE table_a and FLUSH TABLE table_b on the "slow" database fixed my issue. As for what is big, table_a is 1.7 million rows, table_b is 13 thousand. But I think the problem is in data statistics being out of date. I wonder how often AWS RDS updates them (this is where the server is).

table_a is 1.7 million rows, table_b is 13 thousand These are small tables - from SQL looking point. I think the problem is in data statistics being out of date. Read about table statistic in MySQL... at least something. ANALYZE TABLE Statement

I have eventually solved the problem by using STRAIGHT JOIN.
Apparently, the optimizer considers the number of rows in both tables to choose the order in which the tables are joined. Since I am sorting on the PK of table_a, starting with table_b is always a bad idea, even if there are significantly less rows in table_b than in table_a.
This is the query I ended up using:
SELECT STRAIGHT JOIN *
FROM table_a
JOIN table_b ON table_b.id = table_a.table_b_id
ORDER BY table_a.id
LIMIT 100

I would not have figured this out without the helpful comments, so thank you!
